# SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments returns null

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, simulator

What could be the reason that SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments always returns null? I run in Simluator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning false because you are running it in the simulator and you can't make app purchases from the simulator

Comment: You can now make payments in the simulator via iOS 5.X (using apple's sandbox)